# CLAMP can not run the Ruta Rules for predicting the relationships

Tags: ruta, clamp

I am trying to implement relationship ruta rules same as in this video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=1105&v=8PYvzswOXog). 
However, I can not get the results of any relationships. 
I did perfectly follow everything in his demo.

Any help is appreciated.

```
BLOCK (ForEach) Sentence{}{                                                                                                                       
   ClampNameEntityUIMA { FEATURE ( "semanticTag", "test")}
   BaseToken??{REGEXP("grade")}
   ClampNameEntityUIMA { FEATURE ( "semanticTag", "Date" ) -> CREATE( ClampRelationUIMA, "entFrom"=3, "entTo"=1), SETFEATURE("semanticTag", "testdate")};                                                            
}

BLOCK (ForEach) Sentence{}{
    ClampNameEntityUIMA { FEATURE ( "semanticTag", "test")}
    BaseToken??{REGEXP("[grade\\s]*")}
    ClampNameEntityUIMA { FEATURE ( "semanticTag", "value" ) -> CREATE( ClampRelationUIMA, "entFrom"=3, "entTo"=1), SETFEATURE("semanticTag", "testvalue")};
}
```

Comment: Do you get an error or the wrong result?

Comment: No, the pipeline performed without errors. I can not see any relationship :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like that you actually want to use the `GATHER` action instead of the `CREATE` action. The `GATHER` action is able to assign the values of a feature using the index of the rule element whereas the matched annotation of the matching condition is assigned to the feature. The `CREATE` action tries to assign the given argument to the feature. In your example, that is an integer for a feature with an annotation range, which will result in no assignment.

Your block could look like:

```
BLOCK (ForEach) Sentence{}{                                                                                                                       
   ClampNameEntityUIMA { FEATURE ( "semanticTag", "test")}
   BaseToken??{REGEXP("grade")}
   ClampNameEntityUIMA { FEATURE ( "semanticTag", "Date" ) -> GATHER( ClampRelationUIMA, "entFrom"=3, "entTo"=1), SETFEATURE("semanticTag", "testdate")};                                                            
}
```

DISCLAIMER: I ama developer of UIMA Ruta

Comment: thank you so much. Yes, I was using create. It is not clear what he was typing in the demo.